# Does PostageApp support standard ActionMailer templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, postageapp

I previously had a test mailer working (based on the RailsGuides tutorial). When I integrate PostageApp gem and inherit from PostageApp, I get this:

```
@message="Message layout Provided Message Template is not found., Content can't be blank"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you're not sending any content over. You are also specifying a `postageapp_template` that doesn't exists in your PostageApp project for some reason.

Try figuring out what exactly is being sent. In your test (you have tests, right?) have something like this:

```
email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
raise email.arguments_to_send.to_yaml
```

You'll see the actual payload. That should give you a pretty good idea what's missing.

Comment: I didn't specify any postageapp_template though as it was just a standard actionmailer example, which worked on a standard SMTP setup. I didn't try that test, but it seems like the Gem is assuming a postageapp_template must be specified, so wouldn't work with a standard actionmailer call.

Comment: @mahemoff If you edit your question to include your mailer class and output of the code I posted above, I think we'll be able to find what's the problem.

Comment: I sent an example to postageapp support separately, but I really just wanted to ask here if it's supposed to work or not. ie does the current postageapp gem actually support standard ActionMailer templates? Or is postageapp templating a requirement? I'm now using the templates for my own case anyway, so I've fixed it for my current situation anyway.

Comment: @mahemoff No, templating is not a requirement. You really should only need to switch `ActionMailer::Base` to `PostageApp::Mailer` with no other changes. Plugin just a wrapper for ActionMailer. At the end it grabs content rendered and constructs an API call. You can dig through the code if you're feeling adventurous: https://github.com/postageapp/postageapp-ruby/blob/master/lib/postageapp/mailer/mailer_3.rb